# QTableView real-time filtering

Tags: c++, qt, filtering, qtableview

My situation looks like this: I have QTableView and LineEdit. I'd like to show data which contains value in LineEdit in real time. I guess I should use QSortProxyFilterModel, but I don't know how to do that. I wrote this:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineFind_textEdited(const QString &arg1)
{

QSortFilterProxyModel proxy;
proxy.setSourceModel(ui->tableView->model());
proxy.setFilterRegExp(arg1);
QModelIndex index=proxy.mapToSource(proxy.index(0,0));
if(index.isValid())
  {
    ui->tableView->selectionModel()->select(index,QItemSelectionModel::Select | QItemSelectionModel::Rows);
    ui->tableView->scrollTo(index,QAbstractItemView::EnsureVisible);
  }


}
```

But it doesn't work (no change visible). Example how it should work: Clementine Player playlist.

Comment: Why are you using hard-coded index co-ordinates? `QModelIndex index=proxy.mapToSource(proxy.index(0,0));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create `QSortFilterProxyModel` and destroy it immediately in your function. It's incorrect use. You need to create one object of QSortFilterProxyModel (maybe using `new`), then call `QTableView::setModel` for attaching proxy model to your view. After that changes will take effect.

In the initialization:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
my_model = new QStandardItemModel(); // or any other model class
proxy_model = new QSortFilterProxyModel();
ui->table_view->setModel(proxy_model);
proxy_model->setSourceModel(my_model);
```

In textEdited slot:

```
proxy_model->setFilterRegExp(arg1);
```

Comment: Who takes ownership of what here? Will the proxymodel be deleted by the view or am I responsible for both?